# best way to debug python in pysnopper

Tags: python, debugging

How can I use pysnopper to debug subclass running? I have import a class through pip install. Pysnopper only shows me  which is not quite helpful since I should see what is going on there too. Can someone show me how ?

Using this not quite help.
@pysnooper.snoop(depth=5)
@pysnooper.snoop(watch_explode=('function1','self'))

Also, If any new debugger you think can do, please share.

Comment: since subclass pass by object and it only return obj = <class object at 0x7f9433c03d90>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using watch_explode with the main function works since everything go through main